# Getting setuptools to ignore PyPI repository

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I have in my packages `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    dependency_links=['http://local.mirror'],
    install_requires=[
        'many',
        'different',
        'packages',
    ],
    ...
 )
```

What seems to happen is that setuptools will load entries from install_requires in reverse order, and it will respect the `dependency_links` entry for only the last entry in `install_requires` (it installs things in reverse order).

There's plenty of discussion about how to add packages that aren't in PyPI, but I can't seem to find my way about ensuring that my local entry is used first, or exclusively.

Comment: how are you invoking the setuptools? with or without pip/easyinstall/... ?

Comment: Have you tried the `--find-links (-f): additional URL(s) to search for packages` option of `pip` / `easy_install`?

Comment: Direct execution of `python setup.py`, which uses `setuptools.setup()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing the following `setup.cfg` file in the same location as `setup.py` has addressed this:

```
[easy_install]
allow_hosts = local.mirror
```