# Deploy a pyramid application with sdist

Tags: python, pyramid

I am new at pyramid framework and I recently started to play with it. However, I'm a bit confused about how a tarball created with 'sdist' gets installed in a production virtual environment. My scenario is as follows:

1. After finishing a project I created in pyramid called 'myapp', I run: python setup.py sdist in order to create the distribution tarball.
2. The tarball gets created under 'dist' folder and it contains all my project sources as well as the .ini files (development and production).
3. I then create a new production virtual environment by executing: virtualenv --no-site-packages envprod
4. To install the 'myapp' distribution tarball I execute: envprod/bin/easy_install src/myapp/dist/myapp0-0.tar.gz.
5. It then starts to download and install all the requirements for the project and it also installs the sources of my application under envprod/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myapp

The problem is that neither development.ini nor production.ini are installed in the new prod environment so I have no way to execute 'pserve' since it needs the .ini file.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a way to start serving 'myapp' without the .ini files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you misunderstand what is product and configuration. Your `.ini` file isn't part of your application. The same way as nginx configuration isn't part of nginx distributions. So, generally you need to separate your product code from configuration. Depending on what do you prefer you can use virtualenv or buildout. I see that you already use virtualenv but it is only allow you to install python eggs, if you want to have more automation then you can find set of [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) recepies for pyramid that can make initial setup little easier.

Usually `.ini` files contains database connection string, ports or path to log files folder. You can have example `.ini` file for your project but you don't need to store it inside of project eggs file (in your example `myapp0-0.tar.gz.`).

Second part is how to distribute your project. You noticed that most python projects can be downloaded from PyPI (virtualenv do this). If you don't want to open source your work then you can *install own PyPI server* (just google it, there is plenty of [examples](http://justcramer.com/2011/04/04/setting-up-your-own-pypi-server/)). Then you will be able to deploy on your production server just using your *own PyPI mirror* and don't need to upload project files in public. [Upload with this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299439/getting-setuptools-to-ignore-pypi-repository):

```
$ python setup.py sdist upload
```

And install string on your server:

```
(envprod)$ pip install -i http://my.mirr.or/path $PACKAGE
```

Last part is how to organize skeleton for your production environment. You can make another project in your DCVS with `.ini`, `requirements.txt` files examples, initial folder structure and just clone to your production server. I prefer to use `Makefiles` to do initial work like setup `virtualenv`, run `pip`, download static jQuery (if you don't use CDNs for example).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation Mikhail! It makes sense now. I will read about buildout and recipes created by the community since I think that might be what I am needing.

Comment: Just want to warn you, buildout configuration can be confusing sometimes. And don't use it inside of virtualenv ;)

Comment: Ah ok, great. Thanks for the warning. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Mikhail, code and configuration are note the same. 
You may want to deploy your package manytimes and not to overwrite already installed configuration and data.
Please note that the db, if present and on file system (sqlite), is not distributed inside the package as well. I guess it's done to allow you to update the code easily.

If your intent is to deploy the package in production environment all you need to do is to copy both the ini you want to use and the database (if sqlite) or to run the initilize_db script (that is installed in bin) before starting the app.
Note that it's always a good idea to test the production ini in a non production environment to be sure that settings are good for you, in particular about logging, because you'll have no console logging.

Though it's good enough for dev/prod environment, it may be a problem for distribution to 3rd party. 
I'm just trying to address similar problems and I think that the main point is to properly configure setup.py and MANIFEST.in, to include what you need in the egg and properly extract them when installing. 
The problem seems to be that easy_install skip all files outside your app folder (so ini files, that are one dir back).

A workaround for that, is to skip easy_install, and just untaz your tarball and then enter your project folder and use:
  pip install -e . --pre
(the --pre is only required if you included pre-release package in your project, maybe because they are a dependency of formalchemy, as I did).
This seems the easiest way toi distribute to other people.
You may want to create the database somehow, anyway, to have it work, unless you include it in the distribution explicitly adding it to MANIFEST file.