# Creating setup.py for my python project , issue with downloading dependent packages

Tags: python, django, packaging, setuptools, setup.py

This is my setup.py file

```
try:
   from setuptools import setup, find_packages
except ImportError:
   from ez_setup import use_setuptools
   use_setuptools()
   from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
   name='test',
   version='0.1',
   description='',
   author='',
   author_email='',
   install_requires=[
      'django >= 1.2.3',
      'pyxmlsec',
      'south',
      'lxml',
      'xlrd'
   ],
   packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup']),
   include_package_data=True,
   test_suite='nose.collector',
)
```

After running the command `python setup.py install` , it installs the `.egg` in my `site_packges` but while installing the dependencies  it throws errors :

```
 Processing dependencies for test==0.1
 Searching for lxml
 Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
 Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
 Couldn't find index page for 'lxml' (maybe misspelled?)
 Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
 Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
 Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
 No local packages or download links found for lxml
 error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('lxml')
```

Not only for `lxml` module,the same error is happening for all other modules like `xlrd` . The attempted `pypi` link is fine with the source code . So what can be the solution? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is a connectivity issue. Are you connected to the internet? If using a proxy, is your proxy setup correctly (I am assuming linux) in your environment? Can you manually install packages by doing `pip install lxml` or `easy_install lxml`

Comment: @RedBaron yes i can do install the modules manually , but actually I want that while transfering the code in many client machines , they should not download and install all the modules manually , running a simple script will do that. So i develop such `setup.py` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many users reports problems with pypi downs, maybe you solve by using a [mirror](http://www.pypi-mirrors.org/) or since you have many clients (I guess in the same network/organization) a [local pypi server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1235331/2343488) should be a nice solution, here is a list of [pypi alternatives](http://uyeya.blogspot.com/2013/10/list-of-local-alternatives-of-pypi.html) that I have done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try to use this `mirror` solution. But cant use the `local pypi server` as they all are not in the asme network.

Comment: also with the present script how to force to install all the dependency modules from mirror server. Any idea:)

Comment: Try with [this](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi), also look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13406367/2343488), I don't tested it but seem usefull. besides you can instruct your clients to specify the pypi server when install your package, i.e. `pip install -i http://pypi-mirror-server yourpackage`

Comment: seems to be very useful link .